# How to make Frontrun bot faster

Tags: transactions, gas, pending-transactions, bot

Do you have any tips?
I want to make sure, that my transaction will be placed in the block of the transaction to frontrun

Comment: * On the Binance Smart Chain

Answer (score 1):

Miners decide transaction order and inclusion in their block by solving the knapsack problem, if your transaction satisfies the conditions better, it will be included earlier more often.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

The most effective way to do this is that your transaction is smaller and has a higher gas price.

If you can't meet one of the conditions try to optimize for the other (IE: your tx is much bigger you need to set a bigger gas price than you usually would)

To get the transaction price of the tx you are trying to frontrun first get the receipt
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth.html#gettransaction

And to get the gas used you can emulate it yourself with
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth.html#estimategas

You can skip those steps if you already know the price and gas of the transaction.

Best of luck!